# Change the way Visual Studio refactors uppercase properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring

I have a problem in the way how Visual Studio refactors uppercase properties.
Here is some simple class:

```C#
    public class TEST
    {
        public string MY_STRING { get; set; }
    }
```

Now i using CTRL+ to refactor my property -> "Convert to full property"
Visual Studio is creating code

```C#
    public class TEST
    {
        private string mY_STRING;

        public string MY_STRING { get => mY_STRING; set => mY_STRING = value; }
    }
```

I would like my fields to be lowercase, like this:

```C#
    public class TEST
    {
        private string my_string;

        public string MY_STRING { get => my_string; set => my_string = value; }
    }
```

Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: You can use [.editorconfig naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-naming-conventions?view=vs-2019) to tell VS how your properties should be cased, and it should respect those when doing refactorings. That said, please just follow the same rules as everyone else

Comment: Before it's too late, check official [naming guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines). You and your software source going to have problems.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to choose field text and Ctrl+U.

Second, you use Ctrl+R, E to refactor properties.

Result:

[image]